# sizeof a structure vs the offset of last element of the structure

Tags: linux, gcc, sizeof, offsetof

I have a C structure comprising of a couple of elements. When i type offsetof() on the last element of the structure, it shows 144 and sizeof() the last element is 4. So, I was assuming the size of the structure is 148. However, running sizeof() on the structure itself returns a value of 152. Is there something I am misinterpreting about the offset? Shouldn't the size of the structure be 148 instead of 152? Is there some sort of padding that is being applied to fit the byte? I am running on a 64bit platform on Ubuntu 14.

```
Struct A{
// few elements 
};

Struct B{
 Struct A;
 <type> C;
 <type> D;
 // few more elements
};
```

element C is at a offset of 148(may be because padding is not applied), but the sizeof struct A is 152(quite possibly due to padding) and hence, when memcpy is performed, the value assigned to element C gets zeroed out.

UPDATE : Just verified sizeof() element C is 4 bytes and hence, it makes sense it gets included immediately after 148th offset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: Seems quite close to what i may be looking, my 32 bit exe doesn't seem to cause any problem. However, 64 bit does. Will look more closer at the #pragma settings.

Comment: How is the padding after the last member a problem? It's there for a reason.

Comment: Actually, this same structure is included in another structure which has few more members after it. The member immediately after the first structure is at a offset of 148 but since we are doing memcpy from a padded structure resulting in a sizeof 152, the content of the member in the second structure gets overwritten with zero and hence, the value resets to zero...

Comment: If the actual problem is that a member is being incorrectly overwritten, you should probably post a new question asking about that, with a self-contained program that illustrates the actual behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no padding, al least not before or after the structure. However if you use different datatypes within the same structute sometimes an [alignment](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch19lev1sec3) is added for performance. This is a compiler settings and if you want you can disable it.